# Set connection timeout for Parse queries

Tags: parse-platform, connection-timeout

I'm testing a query on Parse using the `findInBackground()` method under different connection types.
When connection is not available, there are times in which the `done()` callback returns, as expected, the following exception after few seconds:

```
com.parse.ParseException: i/o failure: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://api.parse.com refused
```

But there are times in which it takes like 30-60 seconds to be thrown, or even is not called at all.

Is there a way to control this behavior? I would like to set a fixed timeout, like 10 seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could have your own timer that starts when you run `findInBackground`. If the timer is exceeded before `findInBackground` responds, then you could update you app appropriately. When the `findInBackground` finally does respond back, you can ignore the response.

If you tell me which language you're using, I could probably come up with actual code if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've already implemented this method by myself. I just hoped there was a "native" functionality in the Parse SDK for this purpose, but apparently not.